# nodejs express redirecting from within a event handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express

The nodejs application I am working on is written using express and 
routing middle ware. I am adding some kind of licensing functionality to 
this  application, where it checks periodically checks for the expiry.

After it finds it is expired, it emits an authorization failed event
which caught in event handler. I want to redirect or open a new page from 
within the event handler.

1. Is this is the right approach? (I am new to node and js)
2. I don't have access to response object in the event handler. 
   So in such case how I redirect to a different page?

   ```
   //Start of the code
   var app = express();

   //view engine setup
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');
   //Deleted the code to keep it minimal

   app.use('/', routes);
   app.use('/sensor', sensorPage);
   app.use('/export', exportPage);
   app.use('/exportsensormetrics', exportSensorMetricsPage);

   //Error Handling
   app.use(function(req, res, next)
   {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err.status = 404;
   next(err);
   });


   //The product key authorise() function periodically checks for expiry


   var authutils = require('./authutils.js');
   authutils.authorise();

   //This is the Event Handler

   authutils.authEvent.on('authorisation', function(data)
   {
       if(data == 'passed')
   {
       utils.dump("authutils::authEvent::on: Authorisation Passed");
   }
   else if(data == 'failed')
   {
       //Auth failed
       //I want to redirect from here and open page which says expired
       //Can I redirect from here?
   }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn how use Express - it's read official [**docs**](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

---

Check license middleware

```
function checkLicense(req, res, next) {
    if (*check*)
        next(); // move to sensorPage 
    else
        next(new Error('License exiped')); // move to first registered error-middlware
}
```

Assign this middleware to application

```
app.use(checkLicense); // if you want check all request
...
app.use('/sensor', checkLicense, sensorPage); // if you need check only specific route
```

Error middleware must have first argument error

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {...});
```

Comment: Thank you Aikon for the reply. Is there a way I can avoid tying this up with requests? I want to run this check in the background and whenever it hits the condition, I want to open a page?

Comment: It's a little strange, but you can do it. Simple way is: client send ajax-request to server each N second and parse server answer. If license is not check then client do `location.href = '/badLicense'`. Another way is use websocket: server validate license by timer all of clients and send message via websocket that license is not valid. Client receive it and go to `badLicense` page.

Comment: Thanks Aikon. I used the second approach of using Webscokets to communicate with the clients and it's working. Thank you very much